# delete variable extesions on bash linux on folder

Tags: linux, bash, variables, rename

Hi guys i need to eliminate " variables extensions" of files in a folder in linux

format of files : static@varibale

For example:

Folder day one (automatic saved running-config cisco on a tftp server)

> ls folder
>
> SW-ANATOMIA-PAT@Sep-19-16-09-49.092-0
>
> SW-LAB@Sep-19-16-09-49.092-0
>
> SW-URGENCIA@Sep-19-16-09-49.092-0

folder day two

> ls folder
>
> SW-ANATOMIA-PAT@Sep-20-16-09-49.092-3
>
> SW-LAB@Sep-20-16-09-49.045-0
>
> SW-URGENCIA@Sep-20-16-09-49.042-7

need this to stay this way

> SW-ANATOMIA-PAT
>
> SW-LAB
>
> SW-URGENCIA

your help will be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
for file in *@*; do
    mv "$file" "${file%@*}"
done
```

- `*` is a wildcard that matches any character. See [this guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns) for more information on globs in `bash`.
- `${file%@*}` expands to remove all characters after the last occurrence of `@` stored in parameter `file`.